# Can I have subdomain of my website on different Technology?

Tags: reactjs, angular, subdomain

My main website in on React. Now I want to include a 3 sub domains and want those sub domain on Angular. So my questions is can i do the sub domain as a website on different technology?

Comment: Yes, you can. Each subdomain can map to a different server if you want

Comment: You can have them even on the same domain. The server doesn't care what libraries it serves. They're just files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes you can have different domains or even one domain with different routes with react, angular, etc.
To make this life you need to set up redirect logic on your load balancer or server where you are hosting to resolve where traffic must go, also u need to remember that navigation between 2 microservices (for example angular and react) will be with full reload (without SPA).